# Why it truncates differently both of the panels have the same styles though?

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

A first panel word - **Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)**

The second one is - **BK550Y (Intel(R) Display Audio)**

Could this be a problem with **react-native-windows** implementation?

[image]

Comment: By the way, I'm using a prop **numberOfLines** to achieve that truncate effect. According to the docs it's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/2849. In the newer versions, it should be fixed(https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/pull/2878).